# mkString and sortByKey are not working with Arrays in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a log file (accounts) with a data as the following:

```
1,2008-10-23 16:05:05.0,\N,Donald,Becton,2275 Washburn Street,Oakland,CA,94660,5100032418,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0
2,2008-11-12 03:00:01.0,\N,Donna,Jones,3885 Elliott Street,San Francisco,CA,94171,4150835799,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0,2014-03-18 13:29:47.0
```

1- I got the log file using:

```
val accountsdata = sc.textFile("C:/Users/Sam/Downloads/account1.txt")
```

2- I wanted to key accounts by postal/zip code, so I did the following:
`val accountsByPCode = accountsdata.keyBy(line => line.split(',') (8)).mapValues(line => line.split(","))` ---> This works fine.

3- Then I wanted to map accountsByPCode to lastname,firstname as the values, and I did it using the following: 
`val namesByPCode = accountsByPCode.mapValues(fields => (fields(3),  fields(4))).collect()` --> This works fine too, but when I tried to print it using:

```
println(s"======= namesByPCode, style1 =======")
 for (pair <- namesByPCode.take(5)) {
  printf("%s, [%s] \n",pair._1,pair._2.mkString(","))
 }
```

I got this error:

```
error: value mkString is not a member of (String, String)
  printf("%s, [%s] \n",pair._1,pair._2.mkString(","))
                                   ^
```

Also when I tried to sortByKey using:

```
println(s"======= namesByPCode, style2 =======")
 for (pair <- namesByPCode.sortByKey().take(5)) {
  println("---" + pair._1)
  pair._2.take(3)foreach(println) 
}
```

I got the following error:

```
error: value sortByKey is not a member of Array[(String, (String,String))]
  for (pair <- namesByPCode.sortByKey().take(5)) {
                          ^
```

Can someone advise what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error in

```
error: value sortByKey is not a member of Array[(String, (String,String))]
  for (pair <- namesByPCode.sortByKey().take(5)) {
```

just because you did collect on the previous step

```
val namesByPCode = accountsByPCode.mapValues(fields => (fields(3),  fields(4))).collect()
```

Since you called `collect()` you don't have an RDD anymore. You are working with an array. You just need to sort data by key before collecting.

```
val namesByPCode = accountsByPCode.mapValues(fields => (fields(3),  fields(4))).sortByKey().collect()
```

Now you have a sorted array. And if you don't need the whole array, you should replace `collect()` with `take(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are creating a `Tuple2[String,String]` not an `Array[String]`. Try:

```
val namesByPCode = accountsByPCode.mapValues(fields => Array(fields(3), fields(4))).collect()
```

Or else change the code where you pick it apart to this:

```
printf("%s, [%s] \n",pair._1,Array(pair._2._1, pair._2._2).mkString(","))
```

Do one of those (don't do both!).

Comment: Now the mkString is working, but the sortByKey is giving me this error: <console>:39: error: value sortByKey is not a member of Array[(String, Array[String])]